# Error OleDbException was unhandled in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm using access database to input student number,student name and contact number(all are in text data type) 
I have already created a small form with three text boxes to input the above mentioned details and a button to save them in my database

here is the code ~~~~~

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;



namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
         {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=");
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        string sql;


    public Form5()         
    {
     InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();   
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                     
        sql = "INSERT INTO table1 values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"')";

        cmd=new OleDbCommand(sql,con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();                                            


    }
}
```

}

the database file is saved in the bin/debug folder of my program
and when i run the program i get the error in line con.open(); as "OldDbException was unhandled No error message available, result code:DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED
(0x80040E4D)."

I tried changing so many codes but  still i get this statement . I also tried removing this "@" sign in the following line but still it didn't make any difference 
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=");
 
please be free to answer this question for me 
any suggestions,Answers,Ideas or help would be Much appreciated

than you

Comment: Look at the result code: `DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED`. Looks like authentication failed.

Comment: I tried changing almost everything but how can i get it to work??

Comment: your connection string doesn't look good to me ... there isn't even a datasource specified ...

Comment: I'm new to this whole thing ( i mean C# ) so can you please be more specific  , anyway i have saved my access file in the bin/debug folder directory and i tried changing the string several times but still didn't get anything to work..